# Date validation in "Data Annotations Extensions MVC3" not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I am using the date validation included in "Data Annotations Extensions MVC3" in a Razor C# project with Telerik MVC Components but it doesn't work properly. The validation fails for the "19.09.2012" date (german format) because it takes the (month/day/year) pattern. Is there a way to make it work depending on the culture? or it is supossed this validation only works with the mentioned pattern?

http://dataannotationsextensions.org/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I already found the solution:

https://github.com/srkirkland/DataAnnotationsExtensions/issues/33